# php gettext not working on Windows Server 2008, PHP 5.5

Tags: php, windows, gettext

I have a problem getting gettext to work on Windows Server 2008 R2, PHP 5.5

I do the following in my php script:

```
$language = 'NB';
putenv("LANG=".$language);
putenv("LC_ALL=".$language); 
setlocale(LC_ALL, $language);
$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, 'C:/path_to_translations/translations'); 
textdomain($domain);
```

My translation files are in the following directories:

C:/path_to_translations/translations/NB/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
C:/path_to_translations/translations/NB/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo

This works fine on my Windows 7 machine with php 5.3

I guess NB is not really a valid locale name on Windows, but setlocale(LC_ALL, 'NB') still returns 'NB' and not FALSE.
Still, to see if this might have something to do with the problem I have tried setting $language = 'norwegian', in which case setlocale(LC_ALL, 'norwegian') returns 'Norwegian_Norway.1252', and tried to
change the pathnames to both C:/path_to_translations/translations/norwegian/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo and C:/path_to_translations/translations/Norwegian_Norway.1252/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo and also changing the encoding on the .po and .mo files from 'UTF-8' to 'Windows 1252'.
Yet, I can't get the translation to work on the Windows Server 2008 R2, PHP 5.5 machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update. Never got gettext to work with php 5.5, but found other users had similar problems (https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=66265)

Tried installing php 5.4 instead, and now things work as expected.